# How to test for use of a django template block?

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to do the following:

```
{% if appnav %}
<hr />
<div id="appnav">
    <ul class="tabs">
        {% block appnav %}{% endblock %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

...however, testing for the present use of a block by templates further down the inheritance chain does not seem to work.

Is there some other conditional that might do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template language doesn't provide exactly what you're looking for. Child templates can call the parent block with `{{ block.super }}`, but parent templates can't reference child templates.

Your best bet will probably be to write a custom template tag. There are two sections in the template manual to review.

First, [Parsing until another block tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#parsing-until-another-block-tag). This will give you the basics of how to parse.

Second, [Parsing until another block tag and saving contents](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#parsing-until-another-block-tag-and-saving-contents). By placing a block tag inside the custom tag, you could detect content and wrap it as appropriate. This should work, because I believe the inner block tag will be parsed first. If that doesn't work, subclass the existing block template tag provided by django to implement your special magic.

Comment: Thank you... I'll need to do some work and learning to come up with an answer as you've prescribed.

Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

If you you are looking for an easy solution.  You can hide the element as the default html.

```
<div id="appnav">
    <ul class="tabs">
        {% block appnav %}
            <script>document.getElementById("appnav").style.display = "none"</script>
        {% endblock %}
    </ul>
</div>
```